# Select top 1 from temp table returns only first character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a T-SQL code block, I am populating a temp table and doing a `WHILE` loop. In the `WHILE` loop, when I do a `SELECT TOP 1` for a `varchar` value, it returns only the first character.

Here is the code

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RowCounter int;
    SET @RowCounter = 0;

    DECLARE @TotalRows int;  
    SET @TotalRows = 0;

    DECLARE @tempPcsDataId int; 
    SET @tempPcsDataId = 0;

    -- create a temp table
    -- to stack people: PalletLicensePlate in the Db is varchar(50) so I make tempPalletLicensePlate the same
    DECLARE @DistinctPalletsTempTable TABLE 
            (
                 DeliveryDate datetime, 
                 tempPalletLicensePlate varchar(50), 
                 StoreNumber nvarchar(50), 
                 DerivedWmsCode nvarchar(20), 
                 ShipperClid int, 
                 CartonCount int
            );

    -- populate the temp table
    INSERT @DistinctPalletsTempTable 
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            DeliveryDate, PalletLicensePlate, StoreNumber, 
            DerivedWmsCode, ShipperClid, 0
        FROM
            PcsData 
        WHERE
            InsertGuid = '017DA918-3AF3-4F86-949C-C2611E2BEEE8';

    SET @TotalRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @DistinctPalletsTempTable);

    WHILE @TotalRows >= @RowCounter
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @CartonCountForThisPallet int; 
        SET @CartonCountForThisPallet = 0;

        DECLARE @ThisLicensePlate varchar;  
        SET @ThisLicensePlate = (SELECT TOP 1 tempPalletLicensePlate 
                                 FROM @DistinctPalletsTempTable);

        SELECT @ThisLicensePlate  -- this always returns B  The first character
        SET @CartonCountForThisPallet = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                         FROM PcsData 
                                         WHERE PalletLicensePlate = @ThisLicensePlate);

        UPDATE @DistinctPalletsTempTable 
        SET CartonCount = @CartonCountForThisPallet;

        SELECT @RowCounter;
        SELECT @TotalRows;

        SET @RowCounter = @RowCounter + 1;
    END

    SELECT * FROM @DistinctPalletsTempTable;
END
```

Here is a picture of `select * from @DistinctPalletsTempTable;` in the code above.  You can see that tempPalletLicensePlate is a long string

[image]

How can I grab the complete tempPalletLicensePlate from the TOP 1 row?

Comment: What did you expect when you define it as a `varchar(1)`? `DECLARE @ThisLicensePlate varchar; ` The problem has nothing to do with `TOP (1)` at all. I'm also, however, not sure why you're using a `WHILE` in the first place; the whole thing has a smell of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: I see that someone edited the code to be tempPalletLicensePlate varchar(50).  I get the same results with that . SELECT TOP 1 returns one character "B" thanks

Comment: No one editted your code to change it, just format it (with better use of whitespace and line breaks). And the you're looking at the wrong line. Again, `DECLARE @ThisLicensePlate varchar;` is a synonym of `DECLARE @ThisLicensePlate varchar(1);`... A **`varchar(1)`** can only store **one** character.

Comment: A few other suggestions: Always specify all column names to insert into. Don;t just chuck `DISTINCT` at a query to remove duplicates, consider why they are there in the first place. That entire `WHILE` loop could probably be a single joined `UPDATE` statement, SQL likes set-based logic, don;t fall into the trap of writing loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - if you *omit* any length specification, a SQL variable declare as just `varchar` just default to **1 character length** - this is defined, [well documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

*When n isn't specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1*

so no surprise here, really....

And the solution is really simple, too - **always explicitly define** a length when using `varchar` as a datatype - for a variable, or a parameter ....

```
    DECLARE @ThisLicensePlate VARCHAR(50);  -- **DEFINE** then length here!

    SELECT TOP 1 @ThisLicensePlate = tempPalletLicensePlate 
    FROM @DistinctPalletsTempTable;
```

Now your `@ThisLicensePlate` will properly show the **whole** contents of the license plate! The problem really isn't the `SELECT TOP 1....` part - it's the declaration of your SQL variable

Comment: That did it.  I am such a rookie sometimes.

Comment: @pdschuller: glad it worked out - hey, we're still all constantly learning every single day!